# Tag merge request [api.ai] into [dialogflow]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Google acquired API.AI in 2016 and rebranded it as DialogFlow in October 2017.  We currently have separate tags for both API.AI ([api.ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api.ai)) and DialogFlow ([dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow)) though they are referring to the exact same thing.

Many questions are using both tags.

Rebranding announcement: https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/apiai-new-name-dialogflow-new-features/

Comment: So dialogflow will be the master, right?

Comment: @rene - correct